# What's the exact definition of fields in conformal field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, field-theory, conformal-field-theory

For example we work with a 2d scalar field $\phi$. I guess $\phi$, $\partial_z\phi$, $\partial_{\bar z}\phi$ are fields, are there more? Is it true that all fields are in the form of $\partial_z^i\partial^j_{\bar z}\phi$? Are there any context explaining why do we call those 'fields'?

More exactly, in an OPE: $\phi_i(x)\phi_j(0)\sim \sum_k C_{ij}^k \phi_k(0)$, what should we expect those $\phi_k$ to be?

Comment: Start with Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory#Correlation_functions_and_conformal_bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can answer your first question (paraphrasing), "what are the fields in CFT?" Since, I would just take some scalar field $X^\mu(z,\overline{z})$ but then only look at it as an operator (or as a state using the state-operator correspondence), which is where the OPE becomes handy since I can then compute the leading singular terms to it, giving me the UV behavior when the two (or more) operators come into close contact to each other.

As to your second question, consider writing your OPE more carefully and putting the dependence of the positions of your operators in the coefficient $c_{ij}^k$,
\begin{equation}
A_i(\sigma_1)A_j(\sigma_2) = \sum_k c^k_{ij}(\sigma_1-\sigma_2)A_k(\sigma_2).
\end{equation}
So the OPE gives the asymptotic expansion as $\sigma_1\rightarrow \sigma_2$ as a series of poles that are in the $c_{ij}^k$ which govern the dependence on the separation. To make this more concrete, consider two scalar fields (or operators) $X^\mu(z)$ and $X^\nu(w)$ (which have antiholomorphic parts I am too lazy to type out). Their normal ordering plays a crucial role in the OPE which (only up to 0th order approximation in the Taylor series) has an OPE of
\begin{equation}
X^\mu(z)X^\nu(w)\simeq -\frac{\alpha'}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}\ln|z_{12}|^2 + :X^\nu X^\mu(w):
\end{equation}
(which is really just a definition of normal ordering). But we can use this, for example, to find the OPE with the energy momentum tensor $T(z) = -\frac{1}{\alpha'}:\partial X^\mu\partial X_\mu:$ then the OPE with $X^\mu$ is
\begin{equation}
T(z)X^\mu(w) \sim \frac{1}{z-w}\partial X^\mu(w)
\end{equation}
The reason this particular OPE is important is that if the OPE of some operator $A$ with $T(z)$ gives poles $\sim a/z^2 + b/z+\cdots$ with some coefficients $a,b$ athen the operator $A$ is considered a tensor operator or a primary operator $A$. In QFT we usually distinguish the fundamental fields  (the variables of integration in the path integral) from more general operators (that can be composite). This distinction is useful in weakly coupled field theories in $d>3$. But in CFTs, it is of little use do to the equivalence between different field theories, and thus the term field is used for any local operator (confirming my initial point).

So it looks like I hopefully answered both of your questions (the reference I used in Polchinski's string theory volume 1, but also the "Yellow Pages" text by Francesco is good too for CFT).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'd love to rephrase my question as follows: to make OPE valid, those operators $A_k$ should be a complete basis of some linear space, so the set $\{A_k\}$ might should be defined before OPE performed, do we have a description of the set?

Comment: I would say that the notation used in defining the OPE of two operators with the end result of $c_{ij}^kA_k$ (at some point) with $A_k$ being some set of coefficients is misleading. The set of coefficients in the OPE can contain the local operator itself and derivatives of the field ($A$, $\partial A$...) but also just typical coefficients such as $1-2\lambda$ which is the coefficient belonging to the $1/(z-w)^3$ pole in the OPE between $T(z)j(w)$ for the bc CFT. And there is no way to know that coefficient prior to doing that calculation. So I would say there is no defined set prior.